# When sending data to oracle with Nodejs, what is the reason why I do not see the records even though I received an error?

Tags: node.js, oracle, plsql

i have an insert procedure and the in parameter is a table.I enter parameters for the insert procedure, I do not get an error, but whenever I query, I cannot see the records in the table.

This is my PL-SQL Table;

```
 TYPE          t_db2sms_a is table of t_db2sms_r

 TYPE          t_db2sms_r is object
        (
        kullanici                  VARCHAR2(50),
        hesno                      number,
        telno                      VARCHAR2(128),
        mesaj                      VARCHAR2(1024)
        )
```

Procedure Name;

```
  procedure SMS_GONDER (p_ARRAYIN  in t_db2sms_a) ;
```

Procedure Body:

```
procedure SMS_GONDER (p_ARRAYIN  in t_db2sms_a) IS
    v_cnt number:=p_ARRAYIN.count();
    v_err varchar2(4000);
   BEGIN
        insert into sil values (v_cnt);
        commit;
        for i in 1..p_ARRAYIN.count() loop
            insert into sms_db2
            values (
            trunc(sysdate),
            p_ARRAYIN(i).kullanici,
            p_ARRAYIN(i).hesno,
            p_ARRAYIN(i).telno,
            p_ARRAYIN(i).mesaj,
            null,
            0,
            null );
        end loop;
        commit;
   exception when others then 
   v_err:=sqlerrm;
        insert into sil values (v_err);
        commit;
   END;
```

sendSms module;

```
module.exports.sendSms =
{
    typeName1 :"T_DB2SMS_A",
    nlsLang :`alter session set nls_language = "TURKISH"`,
    nlsDateFormat :`alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY'`,
    procedureCall :`BEGIN PKG_DB2.SMS_GONDER(:p_ARRAYIN);END;`

}
```

infoSms module:

```
module.exports.infoSms = function(type,infSms){
   binds ={
      p_ARRAYIN:{
         type:type,
         dir:oracledb.BIND_IN,
         val:infSms
      }
   }
   return binds;
}
```

my execute module ;

```
module.exports = async function(userCodes,customerNo,phoneNumbers,messageText,connection){

    var obj ={
        kullanici:userCodes,
        hesno:customerNo,
        telno:phoneNumbers,
        mesaj:messageText
    }
     
            
        try{
         var tp = await connection.getDbObjectClass(sendSms.typeName1);
         var getBinds =await infoSms(tp,obj)
         await connection.execute(sendSms.nlsLang);
         await connection.execute(sendSms.nlsDateFormat);
         await connection.execute(sendSms.procedureCall,getBinds);
         logger.log('info',obj)
 }catch(e){
    logger.log('error',e.stack)}
    
}
```

This all my Oracle codes and Node js code .I mean I say there is no error but I cannot see my records when I select query. What can I do for  this. What am I missing?

And How can I get succes message or like that any message.

Comment: Test the stored procedure on its own first to check that is working within SQL Developer/TOAD/SQLPlus. If that works then you know the issuse is in the Node.js call.

Comment: its working I think my fault is obj in my execute module. Its going null now

Comment: Some side comments: your code is very inefficient.  (i) See if you can use  a FORALL bulk operation instead of the FOR loop in your PL/SQL code.  (ii) Optimize the node-oracledb call to `begin execute immediate 'alter session set nls_language = "TURKISH" nls_date_format = ''DD/MM/YYYY''';  PKG_DB2.SMS_GONDER(:p_ARRAYIN); end;` or better, use a `sessionCallback` to set the session state, see the documentation: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-15371-nodejs-session-callback

Comment: @ChristopherJones Hello I fixed that thank you. My problem was going on but i solved it.